# Create a virtualenv from inside a python script

Tags: python, virtualenv

i'm working on a simple script in python that creates the folder structure and basic files for a new Flask project, something similar to "django-admin startproject"

what i would like to do at the same time is to create a virtual environment with [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) from inside my script.

i thought that maybe one way could be:

```
import virtualenv

virtualenv.main()
```

the problem is that i can't pass arguments to the main, so this doesn't seem to work.

any suggestion?

Comment: why not just use the 'os' library?

Comment: Try using `import os` and then `os.system('virtualenv venv')`?

Comment: doesn't the os solution have portability issues? isn't there a solution that works without invoking the os?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `os` to pass commands to terminal/cmd.

```
import os

os.system('<command goes here>')
```

You can use that for any commands you'd normally run in terminal.  So for a virtualenv you would just do:

```
import os

os.system('virtualenv nameofvirtualenv')
```

Comment: I don't see any portability issues.